# can't target a hardware smartphone

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to target a hardware smart phone from the Eclipse IDE (run -> run configurations -> target -> select the manual radio button).  When I do this only the emulator phones show up for selection; the smart phone is not available for selecting as the target.  On the smart phone I have checked the Application Settings -> Unknown sources.  This used to work fine on my 1 year old version of the SDK, but now that I have installed the new version of the SDK I can’t do the download.  Is there some trick to the new system, or has Google taken away this capability?  I am not a novice; I have over 1700 downloads for 5 apps on the Android Market.  Inability to cope  with this simple issue makes me feel like an idiot.  I have already submitted this issue yesterday, but I never got a response, and it seems to have disappeared from the system.

Answer (score 0):

No Google has not taken this capability in new version of SDK.

Make sure you have checked Settings > Applications > Development > USB Debugging.

If it is already checked, then uncheck it and again check it.

```
                       OR
```

In Eclipse, Go to devices menu at the right top of device window and click reset adb.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion/directions; however, it did me no good.  I had already done the operations on the smart phone, and I can't find any device window or devices menu in Eclipse.  Do I have a  faulty Eclipse?  Should I reload it?